# Fading text with PNG

Tags: css, png

How can i make a fading text inside

```
<div class="box">
<p>some text, some text</p>
<div class="fading"></div>
</div>

.box {
width: 200px;
}

.fading {
background: url('img/fading.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

but what if i have not a white background for example like here: http://beta.ruh.kz (ПОПУЛЯРНЫЕ СТАТЬИ - called block with text)
How can i do a png fading trick if there's not a white background?

[image: fading text at the bottom]

Comment: Just change `fading.png` to match the background image.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. If you could show us a working example on white background, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is hard to understand but i am trying to help you.
if you want to fade image or text use `fading{opacity:0.7;}` you can change the value accordingly.

or if you want to use an image on coloured background you need to make a transparent png image as in the reference site ...

Answer (score -1):

On this pages:

http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect

http://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

There are tutorials for your problem

Comment: That won't work because: 1) In this example he has just black background, as you can see from my attached image i don't have a just black background (i have stripes) 2) It's CSS3, not all browsers will recognize it.

Comment: The 1 link works without CSS3, just placing an transparent fading image over your text. it doesn't madder what the background-color is. Because the demo has black, it is not that it have to be black.

Comment: From the 1st link clearly says: This trick is only suitable for solid background color elements. Your gradient color (PNG image) must be the same color as your background color.

Comment: -1 okay, i will help you again! the trick on link 1 can be done with a transparent fading image, i thought you will figure that out yourself.

Comment: Can you throw an example? I can't imagine that, i'm already using transparent image... or you didn't understand what i need? Take a look at the picture on my question it doesn't have a solid background.

Comment: you are not very friendly. maybe someone else will help you